# Zend Framework 2 Unable to render template ; resolver could not resolve to a file' in PhpRenderer.php on line 461

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to use ZF2 PhpRenderer without the MVC framework.  Currently I am not able to implement everything but wanted to start re-factoring some stuff into a modified version until I am able to implement the whole framework later in life.

I have been trying to use the Programmer's Reference.

At the top of my tester.php script I have.

```
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel,
    Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer,
    Zend\View\Resolver;
```

Then later on in the script I have this to start trying to render a script.

```
$renderer = new PhpRenderer();

$map = new Resolver\TemplateMapResolver(array(
    'tester' => __DIR__ . '/tester.phtml',
));

$resolver = new Resolver\TemplateMapResolver($map);

$model = new ViewModel();
$model->setVariable('foo', 'bar');
$model->setTemplate('tester');

echo $renderer->render($model);
```

The error I get is this

Unable to render template "tester"; resolver could not resolve to a file' in /home/lumberjacked/workspace/www/vendor/zf2/library/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php on line 461

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution and its pretty simple.  After declaring your $resolver you have to set it in the $renderer.

```
$renderer->setResolver($resolver);
```

I found this in the constructor of the renderer calling this method.